# WinUI3 started printing some annoying messages

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2022 and building a Windows App SDK program using C++.  I am seeing some new messages and wondering if anybody has some hints about how to stop them.  There are a lot of them.  It doesn't seem to cause issues running/debugging the program though.  Here it is:

> onecore\com\combase\registrationstore\registrationstoredata.cpp(1248)\combase.dll!00007FF8ABE56600:
> (caller: 00007FF8ABE343AD) ReturnHr(14196) tid(2188) 80070002 The
> system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: What OS version/build? Can you post a minimal reproducible program?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2022 with WindowsAppSDK 1.0.4.  I can see these messages using the Blank App, Packaged (WinUI 3 in Desktop) template.  No changes just build and run in debug.  The messages are in the Debug Output window in Visual Studio.

Comment: What version of the OS? Settings -> System -> About -> OS build.

Comment: Edition Windows 11 Pro
Version 21H2
Installed on ‎7/‎28/‎2022
OS build 22000.856
Experience Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22000.856.0

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think it means that your app's private hive is missing. Maybe it was deleted by mistake.

Comment: @Zeek - Getting the same error here with a brand new VS WinUI application. It's more than just annoying, I'm seeing some crashes that don't show up in versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: I think the crashes are unrelated. Create a new question for the crashes. And if you can reproduce these error messages, share a project that demonstrates it. As written this question does not offer much to allow diagnosis

Comment: Seeing these myself with Windows App SDK whenever I mouseover elements in WebView2 using WinUI3. Very annoying